# Why would GC.AddMemoryPressure deadlock / hang?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Solved: It turns out that the affected machine had .NET 4.5 beta installed.

---

I have a C# application using .NET4 that deadlocks / hangs indefinitely in a call to

```
GC.AddMemoryPressure(12000000)
```

Since it is an in production app I can't really share any code - however I would like to get some hints on what might make GC.AddMemoryPressure hang.

Comment: Do you have a matching RemoveMemoryPressure call? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2006/10/09/performance-guideline_3a00_-use-addmemorypressure-while-consuming-unmanaged-objects-through-com-interop.aspx

Comment: Why would someone down vote this question without comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your input.

It turns out that the affected machine had .NET 4.5 beta installed.

It seems that it wasn't deadlocked since one core was fully saturated. The call to AddMemoryPressure seemed to end up in the function clr!CNameSpace::GcScanRoots that never returned.

Uninstalling 4.5 beta and installing .NET 4 seems to have fixed the problem.

If this was truly the problem then I sure hope MS fix it before release.

Comment: It looks like it may still be a problem in .Net 4.5 RTM.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/765811/visual-studio-hangs-when-the-xaml-designer-proc-xdesproc-hangs-due-to-system-gc-addmemorypressure-not-returning

Answer (score 2):

Hint from documentation:

> You must ensure that you remove exactly the amount of pressure you
>   add. Failing to do so can adversely affect the performance of the
>   system in applications that run for long periods of time.

That means that you have to be **very** careful in balancing between these two calls:

`AddMemoryPresure` and `RemoveMemoryPreasure`

It's, by the way, suggested to use in case when you allocate a large amount of *unmanaged* resources, in this way signaling `GC` about the fact that it has to take in a count also that amomunt of memory.

In vast magiority of cases the simple `Dispose()`, `Finalize()` correct management would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mess with manual GC. Make sure your resources are disposed of and finished after they are used. GC manually can screw up the system. .NET manages GC pretty well as long as objects are deleted in the program.